# Insert new xml text at specific line

Tags: xml, powershell, insert, line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Tc_data_access_config>
<privileges>
<priv_name>READ</priv_name>
<priv_name>WRITE</priv_name>
<priv_name>COPY</priv_name>
<priv_name>CHANGE</priv_name>
<priv_name>DELETE</priv_name>
</privileges>
<named_acls>
<named_acl>
<acl_name>Working</acl_name>
<acl_name language="fr_FR">working_fr</acl_name>
<acl_name language="de_DE">working_de</acl_name>
<acl_name language="jp_JP">working_jp</acl_name>
<ace_entry>
<accessor_type>group</accessor_type>
<accessor>dba</accessor>
<grant>
<p>READ</p>
<p>WRITE</p>
<p>COPY</p>
</grant>
<revoke>
<p>DELETE</p>
<p>CHANGE</p>
</revoke>
</ace_entry>
<ace_entry>
<accessor_type>Owning Group</accessor_type>
<accessor> </accessor>
<grant>
<p>READ</p>
<p>WRITE</p>
<p>COPY</p>
</grant>
<revoke>
<p>DELETE</p>
<p>CHANGE</p>
</revoke>
</ace_entry>
</named_acl>
<named_acl>
<acl_name>In Project ACL</acl_name>
<acl_name language="fr_FR">In Project ACL fr</acl_name>
<acl_name language="de_DE">In Project ACL de</acl_name>
<acl_name language="jp_JP">In Project ACL jp</acl_name>
<ace_entry>
<accessor_type>group</accessor_type>
<accessor>dba</accessor>
<grant>
<p>READ</p>
<p>WRITE</p>
<p>COPY</p>
</grant>
<revoke>
<p>DELETE</p>
<p>CHANGE</p>
</revoke>
</ace_entry>
<ace_entry>
<accessor_type>Owning Group</accessor_type>
<accessor> </accessor>
<grant>
<p>READ</p>
<p>WRITE</p>
<p>COPY</p>
</grant>
<revoke>
<p>DELETE</p>
<p>CHANGE</p>
</revoke>
</ace_entry>
</named_acl>
</named_acls>
<rule_tree>
<tree_node>
<rule_name>Has Class</rule_name>
<rule_argument>POM_object</rule_argument>
<acl_name></acl_name>
<tree_node>
<rule_name>Has Bypass</rule_name>
<rule_argument>true</rule_argument>
<acl_name>Bypass</acl_name>
</tree_node>
<tree_node>
<rule_name>Has Status</rule_name>
<rule_argument></rule_argument>
<acl_name>Vault</acl_name>
</tree_node>
<tree_node>
<rule_name>Has Class</rule_name>
<rule_argument>POM_application_object</rule_argument>
<acl_name>Working</acl_name>
<tree_node>
<rule_name>Has Class</rule_name>
<rule_argument>Dataset</rule_argument>
<acl_name>Dataset ACL</acl_name>
</tree_node>
</tree_node>
</tree_node>
</rule_tree>
</Tc_data_access_config>
```

Hi,
I have a xml file above where I would like to insert some new data - with automation - the idea is after a specific line number (preferred) or after a specific set of lines (find and insert some multiline tag text afterwards).

Lets say it should find this text:

```
    <tree_node>
<rule_name>Has Class</rule_name>
<rule_argument>POM_object</rule_argument>
<acl_name></acl_name>
<tree_node>
<rule_name>Has Bypass</rule_name>
<rule_argument>true</rule_argument>
<acl_name>Bypass</acl_name>
</tree_node>
<tree_node>
<rule_name>Has Status</rule_name>
<rule_argument></rule_argument>
<acl_name>Vault</acl_name>
</tree_node>
<tree_node>
<rule_name>Has Class</rule_name>
<rule_argument>POM_application_object</rule_argument>
<acl_name>Working</acl_name>
<tree_node>
<rule_name>Has Class</rule_name>
<rule_argument>Dataset</rule_argument>
<acl_name>Dataset ACL</acl_name>
</tree_node>
</tree_node>
</tree_node>
```

And add this afterwards:

```
    <tree_node>
<rule_name>Has BLA</rule_name>
<rule_argument>324234</rule_argument>
<acl_name></acl_name>
<tree_node>
<rule_name>Has TEST</rule_name>
<rule_argument>true</rule_argument>
<acl_name>NO</acl_name>
</tree_node>
<tree_node>
<rule_name>Has BLABLA</rule_name>
<rule_argument></rule_argument>
<acl_name>Vault</acl_name>
</tree_node>
<tree_node>
<rule_name>Has Class</rule_name>
<rule_argument>test</rule_argument>
<acl_name>Working</acl_name>
<tree_node>
<rule_name>Has test</rule_name>
<rule_argument>Dataset</rule_argument>
<acl_name>Dataset ACL</acl_name>
</tree_node>
</tree_node>
</tree_node>
```

Can anything be done in lets say Powershell or some other scripting language?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: SO is not a place where other people do your work for you. Inserting data into XML has been covered several times, so you should be able to find multiple answers showing you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using objects properly you should be able to "dot walk" to the values you need. Something like 
    $c.tree_node.rule_name

Here's part of a wifi script I use. You can see how the file is loaded as an object, then you can dot walk to the property in the XML that you want to work with. Then you can do your PSH foo to change and save the new XML.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse |
Foreach-Object {
  [xml]$c = Get-Content -path $_.fullname

$connections += New-Object pscustomobject -Property @{
  ‘name’ = $c.WLANProfile.name;
  ‘mode’ = $c.WLANProfile.connectionMode;
  ‘ssid’ = $c.WLANProfile.SSIDConfig.SSID.hex

  }
}

$connections | Export-CliXml 
"$($PSScriptRoot)\$($env:COMPUTERNAME)_Backup.xml"
```